# How can I check if a program is running for the first time?

Tags: c#, .net

My program sets its display based on if the program is running for the first time or not. In order to determine if the program is running for the first time I am currently using a

```
//this boolean exists within my programs settings
Setting boolean FirstRun = True;
```

When the program runs it calls a method that checks the state of that bool value and acts accordingly:

```
if(Properties.Settings.FirstRun == true)
{ lblGreetings.Text = "Welcome New User";
  //Change the value since the program has run once now
  Properties.Settings.FirstRun = false;
  Properties.Settings.Save(); }
else
{ lblGreetings.Text = "Welcome Back User"; }
```

It seems to work pretty effectively, however if the .exe file is moved and launched from a new location it considers it a first run, and I'm concerned that I'm doing this in a messy fashion and perhaps there exists a more efficient manner to test for the programs first run. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/622108/check-condition-if-the-appliation-is-running-for-the-first-time-after-being-inst

Comment: You may get a better answer if you go into more details about why you need to know. For example, if you need to ask the user some questions on the first run and you store those answers, the question will reduce to where to store those answers. Also, "first time" is ambiguous -- First time by this user? First time on this machine? The more details you give, the better the answer you'll get.

Comment: Why would you expect an user to move your application?

Comment: @svick: probably that is not an expectation, but experience.

Comment: The program does not install, it runs locally from its .exe file. Therefor if they download the program and run it, then later decide they would like the program to reside somewhere else it views it as a first run. It's not a big problem, but I want the code to be as clean as possible so I thought maybe there was a more efficient way to do it than the way I am. @Tigran: you are correct, though as mentioned it isn't a big deal if they move the program.

Comment: Hi all, is there any firstrun property at Delphi/rad studio Delphi ? Kindly let me know how it can be used at Delphi at rad studio.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems that your problem is actually that if you move `executable` to another location/folder on the **same** pc, it loses somehow the information about the fact that it was already run at least once.

Using `UserSettings`, on `Properties.Settings.Default.FirstRun` should resolve your problem.

Something like this, a *pseudocode*:

```
if(Properties.Settings.Default.FirstRun == true)
{ lblGreetings.Text = "Welcome New User";
  //Change the value since the program has run once now
  Properties.Settings.Default.FirstRun = false;
  Properties.Settings.Default.Save(); }
else
{ lblGreetings.Text = "Welcome Back User"; }
```

Look on [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/UserSettings.aspx) sample how to achieve that in more detailed way.

Comment: This is how my code actually is. I apologize I forgot to type it up that way. Glad that you're recommending the way in which I use it.

Answer (score 7):

Since your question appears to be concerned about each user that launches the application, then you should design a per-user solution.

Using Properties.Settings will actually work and be efficient as long as the setting in question is user-specific.

However, if this is not desired or appropriate for your application, you could also write a user-specific entry to the registry.

For example:

```
        const string REGISTRY_KEY = @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\MyApplication";
        const string REGISTY_VALUE = "FirstRun";
        if (Convert.ToInt32(Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue(REGISTRY_KEY, REGISTY_VALUE, 0)) == 0)
        {
            lblGreetings.Text = "Welcome New User";
            //Change the value since the program has run once now
            Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue(REGISTRY_KEY, REGISTY_VALUE, 1, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        }
        else
        {
            lblGreetings.Text = "Welcome Back User";
        }
```

Comment: Will the registry key get reset to NULL or something similar when you uninstall the app?

Comment: @NeoWin: No, you would need to add a..Net installer class to perform this work or implement this in the installer of your choice.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to guess what is messy if you don't post or describe it.  An obvious approach is to have a setting named "ExePath".  If you get null or a string that doesn't match Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location then it got either just installed or moved.